# Find command script, gpg decryption, and proper shell path

Tags: linux, encryption, find, bash-scripting, gnupg

I wrote a script to encrypt and decrypt symmetrically with find, gpg and inotify. paste a file to samba server, I rename it Encrypted-*, inotify triggers find & runs the commands, encrypts, removes the original.

Decryption works when I create file lisa in the maindir.

Works only from main dir, where encryption works from anywhere using maxdepth.

I think it's because the path set by the script is /opt/Paper/maindir/, but adding that path and maxdepth to the last find command doesnt work.

I know this one is simple. have to set the cwd or properly set the path is the script or something. Help!

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/Paper/maindir/   
#sleep gives files a chance to be written to disk before encryption, otherwise dataloss will occure
sleep 5s
#encrypt
find /opt/Paper/maindir/ -maxdepth 8 -type f \( -iname Encrypted-\* ! -iname Encrypted-\*.gpg \) -exec gpg --yes --batch --passphrase=password -c {} \;        
#remove unencrypted
find /opt/Paper/maindir/ -maxdepth 8 -type f \( -iname Encrypted-\* ! -iname \*.gpg \) -exec rm -f {} \;  
#decrypt and remove lisa
find . -type f -name lisa -exec gpg --yes --batch --passphrase=password --decrypt-files *.gpg \; -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: What prevents the script from just encrypting and deleting every file, with nothing left for the decrypt line? Offhand, if it's just the decrypt that's broken and the first two work ok, it looks like the difference is where find's looking, tried changing the `find .` to `find /opt/Paper/maindir/`?

Comment: It's only looking for that file name and ignoring the extension with the same name. so encrypt when a file is renamed to that, remove the original. works from any directory 8 deep. not pretty but it works. Lisa on the other hand works, but only from the maindir, even with the path set to your suggestion and maxdepth doesnt seem to work with it. doesn't work the way i'd like it to.The issue is the last line, i dont know how to search for 'lisa' and a gpg file at the same time. Wildcard is throwing it off. find lisa where-ever, keep path, delete lisa, decrypt, delete the gpg in the found path.

Comment: Ok then, add some debug / echo's and see what's what, log stdout & stderr, &/or try the commands in question in an interactive terminal and maybe that'll say why they're not working as expected.